# Elasticsearch plugin dependencies for Java

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to include Elasticsearch plugins like marvel and jdbc-importer using the Java API, but I can't figure out how exactly to include them.

It seems like they both use cURL to install them, but I can't figure out how to have Java recognize the plugins. I can't find these plugins on maven repos.

Edit:
Specifically, a lot of the plugin's instructions say to navigate to the directory where you downloaded elasticsearch, but I never downloaded it. I just used the maven dependency so I don't know how to install these plugins. I did find a pom.xml file for jdbc, but there are other plugins that don't have it.